# Why is my state getting mapped one too many times in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, reactfire

Hello i'm trying to `map` my data, which i feched from my Firebase, into a Row of Cards. But since i have the state defined in my `constructor`, one card gets returned with no values at the start. what can i do to avoid the returning of this first empty Card Component ? Thanks in advance.
(the Card Component is a Component with a Thumbnail which i imported)

```
class  List extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.db = firebase.database().ref().child('app').child('cards');

        this.state = {
            cards: [
              {
                id: "",
                cardDesc: "",
                cardPrice: "",
                cardHeading: "",
              }
            ]
          }
        }

      componentWillMount (){
        const previousCards = this.state.cards

        this.db.on('child_added', snap => {
          previousCards.push ({
            id: snap.key,
            cardDesc: snap.val().cardDesc,
            cardPrice: snap.val().cardPrice,
            cardHeading: snap.val().cardHeading,
          })
          this.setState ({
            cards: previousCards
          })
        })
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div className='list'>
          <Row>
          { this.state.cards.map((card) => {
            return(<Card cardHeading={card.cardHeading} cardDesc={card.cardDesc}
               cardPrice={card.cardPrice} key={card.id} />)
                })
          }
          </Row>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default List
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove your initial setup for the state and change your render method to say

```
this.state.cards && this.state.cards.(your stuff)
```

Comment: you mean that i deled my my state in the constructor  and wirte the return function like so ? 


`return(
          <div className='list'>
          <Row>
          { this.state.cards && this.state.cards.map((card) => {
            return(<Card cardHeading={card.cardHeading} cardDesc={card.cardDesc}
               cardPrice={card.cardPrice} key={card.id} />)
                })
          }
          </Row>
          </div>`

Comment: Yes, if you don't have any original state you won't see the blank card, and if you check for the presence of `state.cards` in your render method, no `<Card/>` components will be shown until the state changes.
Your state will change when the `db` call completes, which will cause a `re-render`, pass the null check on `card` and render your mapped `cards` array.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to delay the calling of a render method until data comes back, so you can either check if cards.length <1 and don't display anything or display a loading screen until that data comes back.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but i think you misunderstood it. I don't want to delay something, i want to return all the data from my Firebase. But with this `previousCards` method, it returns the first Card empty and then it returns the Cards with the data. I'm total beginner i'm thankful for any advise.

Comment: It returns the first card empty because your cards array is empty when the component first renders, when you make your firebase request inside componentWillMount the component doesn't wait for data to come back before rendering itself, it just fires the request and renders the component and when data comes back the callback inside of the request gets executed and updates the state which causes a re-render and now your card becomes visible